# Fourier transform of a Gaussian process

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, fourier-transform

I would like to discuss and ask a question regarding the Fourier transform of a Gaussian process, if it makes sense. 
For that purpose, let me describe the following situation.

Let $z(s)$ be a Gaussian process in some space X (e.g., $\mathbb{R}^2$).
We can construct such a Gaussian process (following Higdon, 1998) when:

$$z(s) = k(s)\ast\nu(s) = \int_{X}k(u-s)\nu(s)du,$$

where $\ast$ is the convolution operator, $k$ is the smoothing kernel function and $\nu(s)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\lambda_s^{-1})$ is a white noice process. 
Then, if $k$ is isotropic (dependent on distance only), one can compute its covariance simply by using the Convolution theorem:

$$\Sigma = cov(z(s), z(s')) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}[k(s)\ast k(s')]] = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[K^2(w)],$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ are the Fourier and inverse Fourier transform operator respectively, and $K(w)$ is the Fourier transform of the kernel function.

I would like to actually work with the Fourier spectra of my data, meaning I would like to sample the parameters space of my Gaussian process in reciprocal space. The reason is that I know that $k$ is isotropic and I have the full form of $K$, so working in Fourier space would save me the computation cost of taking inverse Fourier Transform of my kernel function (the data itself is already in Fourier component so working in Fourier space would save me two transforms).

We know that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ is itself Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{\sigma})$.

Does that mean that if $z(s)\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$, its fourier transform is $Z(w)\sim\mathcal{N}(0, K^2(w))$?

Any comments, discussions, and/or reading recommendations will be more than welcome!

Thank you in advances! Looking forward to the replies!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520713/fourier-transform-of-a-multivariate-gaussian

Comment: Your introduction is a bit difficult to follow. How do you get to $z(s) \sim N(0,\Sigma)$ and why should the transform *only* relate to $K$? (Is $\Sigma$ only related to $k$ and $K$, and not also to $\lambda_s$? Where do we see the $\lambda_s$ in $Z(w)$? How does the convolution theorem part eliminate it?)

Comment: Recall that the fourier transform of a guassian is a gaussian.  If the covariance matrix is non-diagonal, diagonalize the matrix -> change basis -> compute fourier transform -> revert to original basis.  

Are you familiar with multivariate gaussian Fourier transforms?

Comment: Thank you @MartijnWeterings. I am aware on how to take the Fourier transform of a multivariate Gaussian. The question was more on how does the covariance of the transform relates to the covariances of the real space distribution, knowing that the real-space covariance is distance-dependent itself. Here, the Fourier transform is on the distance. So propagating the transform not just on the distribution but on the covariance too. Does this clarifies the question? Thanks again for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Chapter 11 of the book *Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes* has this result: The Fourier transform of a stochastic process $x(t)$ is a stochastic process $\mathbf{X}(w)$ given by $$
\mathbf{X}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{X}(t) e^{-i \omega t} d t
$$ I changed out the $j$ they had for the more common $i$ to denote $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: The Fourier transform of an infinite duration stochastic process is not well-defined. Instead we work with the "[spectral density](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density)", which for stationary processes (Gaussian or otherwise) is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation $E[X_{t+\tau}X_{t}]$ (a deterministic quantity).